# Why is this Entity Framework association not loading lazily?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using a Code First Entity Framework approach, and in my `OnModelCreating` function I have the following code:

```
With modelBuilder.Entity(Of FS_Item)()
   .HasKey(Function(e) e.ItemKey)
   .Property(Function(e) e.ItemRowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken()
   .HasMany(Function(e) e.ItemInventories) _
   .WithRequired(Function(e) e.Item).HasForeignKey(Function(e) e.ItemKey)
End With
```

Elsewhere I have a Web API Get implementation with some diagnostic code I'm looking at in a debugger:

```
Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As String) As FS_Item
   GetValue = If(data.FS_Item.Where(Function(i) i.ItemNumber = id).SingleOrDefault(), New FS_Item())
   Dim c = GetValue.ItemInventories.Count
End Function
```

I expect that c should get a non-zero value by looking up rows in the FS_Inventory view where ItemKey matches the retrieved FS_Item row's ItemKey. But I'm getting 0 even though there are matching rows. Am I calling `.HasMany`, `.WithRequired` and `.HasForeignKey` properly?

Note that `.WithRequired` is operating on the return value from the previous line whereas the other lines are operating on the `With` block expression.

**Edit** This model for FS_Item has been requested. Here it is:

```
Partial Public Class FS_Item
   Public Property ItemNumber As String
   Public Property ItemDescription As String
   Public Property ItemUM As String
   Public Property ItemRevision As String
   Public Property MakeBuyCode As String
   ' Many many more properties    
   Public Property ItemRowVersion As Byte()
   Public Property ItemKey As Integer

   Private _ItemInventories As ICollection(Of FS_ItemInventory) = New HashSet(Of FS_ItemInventory)
   Public Overridable Property ItemInventories As ICollection(Of FS_ItemInventory)
      Get
         Return _ItemInventories
      End Get
      Friend Set(value As ICollection(Of FS_ItemInventory))
         _ItemInventories = value
      End Set
   End Property

End Class
```

**Edit** Learned something interesting. If I change `Dim c = GetValue.ItemInventories.Count` to this:

```
Dim c = data.FS_ItemInventory.ToList()
Dim correctCount = GetValue.ItemInventories.Count
```

Then correctCount gets the value of 3. It's like it understands the association between the objects, but not how to automatically query them as I'm used to coming from LINQ-to-SQL. Is EF different somehow in this regard?

**Edit** I have determined that I can make the associated objects load using this explicit loading code:

```
data.Entry(GetValue).Collection(Function(e) e.ItemInventories).Load()
```

What I want to understand now is what exactly determines whether an entity will load lazily or not? From all indications I can find, it should have loaded lazily. I even tried changing the declaration of ItemInventories to this, but then I got a NullReferenceException when trying to access it:

```
Public Overridable Property ItemInventories As ICollection(Of FS_ItemInventory)
```

Comment: Can you post the model code for FS_Item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that code which I thought was unrelated had disabled lazy loading. I have this in the constructor of FSDB:

```
DirectCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = False
```

Thanks to [EF 4 - Lazy Loading Without Proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688966/ef-4-lazy-loading-without-proxies) I see that this will also disable lazy loading. The reason that code had been added was due to another error:

> Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.FS_Item_64115A45C642902D6044AFA1AFD239E7DCB82FD000A10FE4F8DE6EA26A2AB418'
>   with data contract name
>   'FS_Item_64115A45C642902D6044AFA1AFD239E7DCB82FD000A10FE4F8DE6EA26A2AB418:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

And according to [Serialization of Entity Framework objects with One to Many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077328/serialization-of-entity-framework-objects-with-one-to-many-relationship), the easy solution for that was to disable proxies.