# Way to load navigation properties after saving object to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

is there any way to 'bind' related properties after saving object to database? For example:
From html form I post ticket object. It has all properties filled and Foregin Keys are correct.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Ticket ticket)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //here i want to use ticket.ResponsibleEmployee property

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(ticket);
}


public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResponsibleEmployee")]
    public int ResponsibleEmployeeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee ResponsibleEmployee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Tickets = new List<Ticket>();
    }
}
```

Is there any simple way to get those related properties? 
I've tried to get property again after save by `db.Tickets.Find(ticket.TicketID)` but returned ticket doesn't have navigation properties assigned. I also tried `db.Entry(ticket).CurrentValues.SetValues(ticket)` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: If you step through your code, does that ticket object have a ResponsibleEmployee before you persist it to the context?

Comment: Try adding the [Key] attribute to Ticket.TicketID and Employee.EmployeeID so EF knows what your primary keys are. By default it will look for TicketId and EmployeeId, but I suspect this is case-sensitive and it isn't creating them automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see any information about the ResponsibleEmployeeID here. But I assume it's part of the object. Then you can try something like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Ticket ticket)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ticket.ResponsibleEmployee = db.Employees.Find(ResponsibleEmployeeID);
        db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(ticket);
}
```

Comment: it's working, but what if I have 5, 10 or 15 related properties? Is there any way to "load" all realated properites?
PS. ResponsibleEmployeeID is set correctly and is a valid Foregin Key.

Comment: Then it's my understanding that you have to connect every one of them before saving changes. So if you have many, you would typically create a private method to handle this before saving.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to 'bind' related properties after saving object to database?

It *depends* on a *lot of assumptions*.

*First*, By looking at the following code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
  db.SaveChanges();
```

It's not possible to tell if `ticket.ResponsibleEmployeeID` is populated.  If it is not populated or does not match a value a related `ResponsibleEmployee.(id/key)` in the database, you won't ever be able to use the navigation property.

*Secondly*, navigation properties can only be *materialized* under a number of circumstances.

The request for the Navigation property has to be within the existence of the context:

```
Ticket ticket;
string employeeName;
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
  // assume 1 exists
  ticket = db.Tickets.Where(t => t.id = 1).First();

  // this is possible (see below why it may not be)
  employeeName = person.ResponsibleEmployee.Name;
}

// this is never possible, the context does not exist
employeeName = person.ResponsibleEmployee.Name;
```

Next, the context has to have [`MyContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.lazyloadingenabled(v=vs.113).aspx).

Lastly, as far as I am aware, [`MyContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.proxycreationenabled(v=vs.113).aspx) also [needs to be true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688966/ef-4-lazy-loading-without-proxies).  If it is not true then the object is disconnected from Entity Framework, and lazy loading is unaware of the object (and anything you try to do, like loading related entities).

If you aren't using proxy object or are not using lazy loading (I don't use either), then you'll have to [explicitly load the related entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232).

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
  var post = context.Posts.Find(2); 

  // Load the blog related to a given post 
  context.Entry(post).Reference(p => p.Blog).Load(); 

  // Load the blog related to a given post using a string  
  context.Entry(post).Reference("Blog").Load(); 

  var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1); 

  // Load the posts related to a given blog 
  context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Posts).Load(); 

  // Load the posts related to a given blog  
  // using a string to specify the relationship 
  context.Entry(blog).Collection("Posts").Load(); 
}
```

Comment: "It's not possible to tell if ticket.ResponsibleEmployeeID is populated." - yes, it is populated and matches a related property. It is selected from DropdownList. Sorry I didn't mention this, I complemented my question. Also, as far as I know LazyLoading is enabled by default so I'm using it.